# Keyboard not responding on CPU boot after HHD Replacement

Tags: windows, usb, keyboard

I just replaced the hard disk on my old computer for a new one but the keyboard won't respond. I have restarted several times and tried all six USB ports each time restarting the machine. Even removed and reinserted the motherboard battery but still no response from the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest checking the connection of the keyboard ribbon cable to the motherboard. If the same problem will persist I would also suggest this troubleshooting steps.

- First is to do a hard reboot, remove the battery and unplug the AC adapter then press and hold the power button for 20 seconds then try booting it up again.
- If the keyboard will still not work, proceed with uninstalling/reinstalling the keyboard driver.
- Go to Device Manager and uninstall the keyboard driver, reboot the laptop once uninstalled and it should reinstall the driver automatically upon reboot.
- If this will still not work, connect an external USB keyboard and test if it will work or not.
- If the external keyboard will work just fine that could mean that the problem is the built in keyboard.
- I would suggest opening the laptop and check the ribbon cable that connects the keyboard to the motherboard.
- Unplug the ribbon cable then plug it back in and test it again.
- If all these will not work then last option would be to replace the keyboard.
- Before considering on replacing the keyboard please do try to reinstall Windows first.

[Source](https://forums.tomsguide.com/threads/keyboard-not-working-after-removal-of-ssd.402971/#:%7E:text=%2D%20First%20is%20to%20do%20a,uninstalling%2Freinstalling%20the%20keyboard%20driver.)